# Read the tasklist (taskmanager data) of other systems connected in a network using Python

Tags: python, networking, tasklist

I know to access tasklist of our machine can be done through os.popen('tasklist').read().

Is there any way to read the tasklist (taskmanager data) of other systems connected in a network using Python?

Just reading them will be fine.

Purpose: Main objective of this is to write a script which will say who has connected to the remote desktop( 'mstsc.exe' in tasklist). 
Suggest if there is any other way to do this.
Thanks.

Comment: Could you explain how you do this __without__ python?

Comment: i was jus looking for an alternate solution if not possible with python. i dint mean that it cant be done with python.